# Why does introducing C++ to a Pico project result in "error: duplicate 'inline'" due to using wrong stdio.h version

Tags: pi-pico

I have a Raspberry Pi (3) with a Pico SDK freshly installed via the [recommended script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberrypi/pico-setup/master/pico_setup.sh).

I've added the [pico-project-generator](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-project-generator.git) and created a project as follows:

```
./pico-project-generator/pico_project.py myProject
```

That empty project builds fine:

```
cd myProject/build
cmake ..
build
```

I then make the following changes, in anticipation of writing + using some C++ classes as the project expands:

```
cd $projectRoot
mv myProject.c myProject.cpp

<also edit CMakeLists.txt to reflect that file rename>
```

The previous `cmake .. ; make` now produces the following errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/newlib/stdio.h:35:0,
                 from /home/pi/pico/myProject/myProject.cpp:1:
/home/pi/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_platform/include/pico/platform.h:237:31: error: duplicate 'inline'
 #define __force_inline inline __always_inline
                               ^
/home/pi/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_platform/include/pico/platform.h:282:1: note: in expansion of macro '__force_inline'
 __force_inline static void __compiler_memory_barrier(void) {
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

<repeats a total of 8 times>

make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/myProject.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/myProject.dir/myProject.cpp.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1559: CMakeFiles/myProject.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

From the official pi-pico-sdk PDF:

> The SDK has a C style API, however the SDK headers may be safely included from C++ code, and the functions called (they are declared with C linkage).
>
> C++ files are integrated into SDK projects in the same way as C files: listing them in your CMakeLists file under either the add_executable() entry, or a separate target_sources() entry to append them to your target.

... which suggests to me that there should be nothing extra/different that I need to do.

The fact that `/usr/include/newlib/stdio.h` appears in the output is sounding alarm bells, but I don't know how to identify how/why that version of `stdio.h` is being used.

This first came to light when a project I wrote months ago would no longer build on this just-re-imaged Pi. The steps above describe the minimal way of triggering the error.

The only code in the project right now is that generated by the `pico-project-generator` template:
**myProject.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"


int main()
{
    stdio_init_all();

    puts("Hello, world!");

    return 0;
}
```

**cMakelists.txt**

```
# Generated Cmake Pico project file

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# initalize pico_sdk from installed location
# (note this can come from environment, CMake cache etc)
set(PICO_SDK_PATH "/home/pi/pico/pico-sdk")

# Pull in Raspberry Pi Pico SDK (must be before project)
include(pico_sdk_import.cmake)

project(myProject C CXX ASM)

# Initialise the Raspberry Pi Pico SDK
pico_sdk_init()

# Add executable. Default name is the project name, version 0.1

add_executable(myProject myProject.cpp )

pico_set_program_name(myProject "myProject")
pico_set_program_version(myProject "0.1")

pico_enable_stdio_uart(myProject 1)
pico_enable_stdio_usb(myProject 0)

# Add the standard library to the build
target_link_libraries(myProject pico_stdlib)

pico_add_extra_outputs(myProject)
```

### Update

I had kept a `.tgz` of my entire `/home/pi` from before re-imaging the Pi. Restoring the older pico SDK from that alongside the new one and switching between them via `PICO_SDK_PATH` etc. confirms that a CMakeLists.txt + C++ source file that won't build with the latest SDK does indeed build just fine with the old SDK.

I've attempted to compare the two `build/Makefile` versions and they are very different.

### Further update

A [GitHub issue has already been raised](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk/issues/659) regarding this error. I've added a minimal example demonstrating the problem there.

Comment: Updated the question with the template code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is down to an [issue exhibited by the 1.3.0 Pico SDK](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk/issues/659) version when used on Raspberry Pi OS "Buster" (and other Debian 10 distros)

It's expected to be addressed by `1.3.1`